# Please merge [window-function] and [window-functions]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Please merge [window-function](/questions/tagged/window-function) and [window-functions](/questions/tagged/window-functions) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I retagged the two window-function questions. I would create a synonym but I don't have the +5 to do it

Comment: @ConradFrix There is only one user with 5 votes in the tag so a mod will have to do it.